# Angularjs how can i add record in Table using array

Tags: angularjs

```
   $scope.JobData = [];    
$scope.SaveData = function (MyData) {
    debugger;
    var _data = [];
    _data = {
        fname: MyData.fname,
        mname: MyData.Mname,
    }
    $scope.JobData.push(_data).toString();
}
```

This is my Table

```
<table class="">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Middle Name</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="_mydata in JobData">
              <td>{{_mydata.fname}}</td>
             <td>{{_mydata.Mname}}</td>

                </tr>
            </tbody>
```

Here how can i appemded my data to the table. Here my intension is add bulk upload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what ever the code you had written is well and good but ur asssign name are not matching with ur table table please see this

```
   _data = {
            fname: MyData.fname,
            Mname: MyData.Mname,
            Lname: MyData.Lname
        }
```

now i hope its work